# Symfony Not able to access dev environment on production server

Tags: php, symfony

Okay, so I am trying to access the dev environment on production server to check a problem and I know I am supposed to add `app_dev.php` example.com/app_dev at the end of the URL and make sure my IP has been added in this file.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

However I still see the message

```
You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.
```

What else I am missing?

Comment: Did you add the value of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in the array ?

Comment: I did remove the code above in question and that did give me access to dev which i feel is risky, so i need to know why my ip is not getting access

Comment: yeah, you'd better understand why the test is returning true and then fix it, than removing it. Test every part of the if statement, separately. Which one returns true ?

Comment: @VaN yes I did add my ip

Comment: then, 1 of the 2 first parts of the if statement is returning true. find which one. Test `php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server'` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose of testing, comment out the whole block and delete the file when your finished testing.

Ideally, you would completely remove those files on a production deployment anyways as it opens you up to potential security loopholes:

1. Someone with good knowledge of Symfony and some ninja-level skills could bypass this and cause heartache.
2. An attacker may assume other similar development files may exist such as `/config.php` and exploit those also.

Again, just comment out the block instead of trying to program it to work. The files should not exist in production anyways.

Comment: Although this solves the problem, I wouldn't suggest it. The development process might be long and people tend to forget stuff. I can't count the times I've encountered projects where the "dev" mode is still on or completely unsecured because somebody forgot to "delete/modify" a file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I always make sure I remove it. How ever I needed to check something that's why I needed to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I think that bit of code is just broken outright. As far as I know, `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])` is always set, even for local requests.

I had to rewrite the check to something more robust, as it suggested.

```
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason causing your problems is the `php_sapi_name()`. If you are running the PHP built in server, the `SAPI` will be `cli-server`, therefore causing an `403` error. It is strongly recommended that you do **NOT** use the built-in server on production servers.

If you, however, want to use the built in server, you need to remove that check and everything should be working.

```
$allowed = array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1');

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowed)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Comment: I don't think I am using built in server on production. Website is hosted on a server, just like any other website